# Infinite loop created when inputting "yy" into a char variable that should only take a single character such as 'y' or 'n', "nn" does not break code

Tags: c++, char

The code in the `cont` function asks the user if they want to play my game again.

The code works when receiving proper character inputs such as **'y'** or **'n'** as well as their respective capital letter variants, and the `else` block works properly to loop the function if an invalid input such as **'a'** or **'c'** is entered.

However during a test run, an input of **'yy'** breaks the code causing the program to infinitely loop, running not only this `cont` function but my `game` function as well.

*choice* is stored as a `char` variable. I am wondering why the code even continues to run upon inputting multi-character inputs such as **'yy'** or **'yes'**. What's interesting is **'nn', 'ny'** and other variations of multi-character inputs that begin with 'n' causes no issues and properly results in the `else if` block running as intended. Which prints "Thanks for playing." then ends the program.

Can variables declared as `char` accept inputs greater than 1 character? Does it only take the first value? And if so why does **'yy'** cause a loop rather than the program running as intended by accepting a value of **'y'** or **'Y'**? How can I change my program so that an input of **'yy'** no longer causes issues, without specific lines targeting inputs such as **'yy'** or **'yes'**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // needed to use strings
#include <cstdlib> // needed to use random numbers
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// declaring functions
void cont();
void game();
void diceRoll();

// variable declaration
  string playerName;
  int balance; // stores player's balance
  int bettingAmount; // amount being bet, input by player
  int guess; // users input for guess
  int dice; // stores the random number
  char choice; 

// main functions
int main()
{
  srand(time(0)); // seeds the random number, generates random number
  cout << "\n\t\t-=-=-= Dice Roll Game =-=-=-\n";
  cout << "\n\nWhat's your name?\n";
  getline(cin, playerName);
  cout << "\nEnter your starting balance to play with : $";
  cin >> balance;

  game();
  cont();
}

// function declaration
void cont()
{
  cin >> choice;
  
  if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
  {
    cout << "\n\n";
    game();
  }
  else if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
  {
    cout << "\n\nThanks for playing.";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "\n\nInvalid input, please type 'y' or 'n'";
    cont(); // calls itself (recursive function!!!)
  }
}

void game()
{
  do
  {
    cout << "\nYour current balance is $ " << balance << "\n";
    cout << "Hey, " << playerName << ", enter amount to bet : $";
    cin >> bettingAmount;
    if(bettingAmount > balance)
      cout << "\nBetting balance can't be more than current balance!\n" << "\nRe-enter bet\n";
  } while(bettingAmount > balance);

  // Get player's numbers
  do 
  {
    cout << "\nA dice will be rolled, guess the side facing up, any number between 1 and 6 : \n";
    cin >> guess;
    if(guess <= 0 || guess > 6 )
    {
      cout << "\nYour guess should be between 1 and 6\n" << "Re-enter guess:\n";
    }
  } while(guess <= 0 || guess > 6); 

  dice = rand() % 6+1;
  diceRoll();

  if (dice == guess)
  {
    cout << "\n\nYou guessed correctly! You won $" << (bettingAmount * 6);
    balance = balance + (bettingAmount * 6);
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "\n\nYou guessed wrong. You lost $" << bettingAmount << "\n";
    balance = balance - bettingAmount;
  }
  cout << "\n" << playerName << ", you now have a balance of $" << balance << "\n";
  if (balance == 0)
  {
    cout << "You're out of money, game over";
  }
  cout << "\nDo you want to play again? type y or n : \n";
  cont();
}

void diceRoll()
{
  cout << "The winning number is " << dice << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I was stripping down the code, but it got to the point where I was no longer able to recreate the problem. 

I just started learning/coding in C++ about a week ago so I'm still unfamiliar with a lot of things as well the best way to post on here.

Upon seeing @SamVarshavchik's answer I see why the problem stopped happening, as I was getting rid of the `game()` function which had the line `cin >> bettingAmount` which was taking the second y input leading the function to loop.

Comment: When you remove something and the problem goes away that’s a clue! Put it back, and remove something else. Keep going until you can’t get rid of anything and still get the problem. That’s not a Stakoverflow thing; that’s how you isolate a bug in your code. It takes practice, but it’s a skill that will serve you well throughout your career.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it only take the first value?

Yes, the `>>` formatted extraction operator, when called for a single `char` value, will read the first non-whitespace character, and stop. Everything after it remains unread.

> why does 'yy' cause a loop

Because the first "y" gets read, for the reasons explained above. The second "y" remains unread.

This is a very common mistake and a misconception about what `>>` does. It does ***not*** read an entire line of typed input. It only reads a single ***value*** after skipping any whitespace that precedes it.

Your program stops until an entire line of input gets typed, followed by `Enter`, but that's not what `>>` reads. It only reads what it's asked to read, and everything else that gets typed in remains unread.

So the program continues to execute, until it reaches this part:

```
cin >> bettingAmount;
```

At this point the next unread character in the input is `y`. The `>>` formatted extraction operator, for an `int` value like this `bettingAmount`, ***requires*** numerical input (following optional whitespace). But the next character is not numerical. It's the character `y`.

This results in the formatted `>>` extraction operator failing. Nothing gets read into `bettingAmount`. It remains completely unaltered by the `>>` operator. Because it is declared in global scope it was zero-initialized. So it remains 0.

In addition to the `>>` extraction operator failing, as part of it failing it sets the input stream to a failed state. When an input stream is in a failed state all subsequent input operation automatically fail without doing anything. And that's why your program ends up in an infinite loop.

Although there is a way to clear the input stream from its failed state this is a clumsy approach. The clean solution is to fix the code that reads input.

If your intent is to stop the program and enter something followed by `Enter` then that's what `std::getline` is for. The shown program uses it to read some of its initial input.

The path of least resistance is to simply use `std::getline` to read ***all*** input. Instead of using `>>` to read a single character use `std::getline` to read the next line of typed in input, into a `std::string`, then check the the string's first character and see what it is. Problem solved.

```
cin >> bettingAmount;
```

And you want to do the same thing here. Otherwise you'll just run into the same problem: mistyped input will result in a failed input operation, and a major headache.

Why do you need this headache? Just use `std::getline` to read text into a `std::string`, construct a `std::istringstream` from it, then use `>>` on the  `std::istringstream`, and check its return value to determine whether it failed, or not. That's a simple way to check for invalid input, and if something other than numeric input was typed in here, you have complete freedom on how to handle bad typed in input.